# Modal popup, Link not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Good day everyone, I have problem on my `modal` popup, the `modal` works but `href` not working i think there is something mistakes on my codes.
please see my code below.

They have only position that the link is working on the modal content.

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop,
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin-left: -280px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  /* IE6-7 */

  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  outline: none;
}
.modal.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .3s linear, top .3s ease-out;
  top: -25%;
}
.modal.fade.in {
  top: 10%;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 9px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.modal-header .close {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.modal-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.modal-form {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer {
  padding: 14px 15px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  *zoom: 1;
}
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.modal-footer:after {
  clear: both;
}
.modal-footer .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.modal-footer .btn-group .btn + .btn {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.modal-footer .btn-block + .btn-block {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <li><a href='#' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal11"><span><b>HR BENEFITS</b></span></a> </li>



<div class="modal fade" id="myModal11" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        
         <img src="Clogo/HHI.png">
         <p>6th Floor, Vernida IV Bldg. 128 LP Leviste St. Salcedo Village, Brgy. Bel Air, Makati City</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <h4 class="modal-title">HR Benefits</h4>
      <p>__________________________________________________________________________________________________</p>
      <br><br>
       <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/ATTENDANCE.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;ATTENDANCE</b></a></p>
       
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/CLEARANCE AND FINAL PAY.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;CLEARANCE AND FINAL PAY</b></a></p>
      
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/COMPANY ISSUED DEVICES ANDOR GADGETS.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;COMPANY ISSUED DEVICES ANDOR GADGETS</b></a></p>
        
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/IDENTIFICATION CARD.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;IDENTIFICATION CARD</b></a>
         <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/IMAGE CODE.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;IMAGE CODE</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/MATERNITY LEAVE.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;MATERNITY LEAVE</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/MEAL ALLOWANCE.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;MEAL ALLOWANCE</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/OFFICIAL HRD ANNOUNCEMENTS.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;OFFICIAL HRD ANNOUNCEMENTS</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/OFFSETTING.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;OFFSETTING</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/OVERTIME.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;OVERTIME</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/PERFORMANCE APPRAISAL.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;PERFORMANCE APPRAISAL</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/PROBATIONARY AND REGULARIZATION.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;PROBATIONARY AND REGULARIZATION</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/SALARY DEDUCTION FOR CASH ADVANCES AND INTERNAL EMPLOYEE PURCHASES.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;SALARY DEDUCTION FOR CASH ADVANCES AND INTERNAL EMPLOYEE PURCHASES</b></p></a>
           <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="PORTALPOLICIES/HR POLICIES AND PROCEDURES/TRANSPORTATION AND ACCOMMODATION ALLOWANCE.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="images/hr.png" width="50px" height="30px"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;TRANSPORTATION AND ACCOMMODATION ALLOWANCE</b></p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <p align="left">This page required to use scrollbar...</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: post your HTML code too.

Comment: You need to provide you HTML code. Can you please add your HTML and CSS code in fiddle.

Comment: Your code look OK, check you "link" URL as after replacing your link URL it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, which you are showing here, anchor tag (`href`) is working fine. But I think problem is with `z-index` there in your code. You should add `z-index` in `.modal-body` may it will helps you.

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100; /*add z-index value here as your need */
}
```